# Get disqus_identifier from web page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, disqus

Can I get disqus_identifier from web page with disqus box. On the page: http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472099-what-is-a-disqus-identifier- you can leave comments using disqus. I want to write the script(maybe beautifulsoup would be useful) which will get the page url as an argument and return disqus_identifier of the discussion on this page. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you read their documentation, a thread_id and a disqus_identifier are not the same thing. But to get the disqus identifier, I'd start with something like:

```
def get_disqus(soup):
    for script in soup.find_all('script',{'type':'text/javascript'}):
        if 'disqusIidentifier' in script.get_text():
            print script.attrs
            print script.get_text()

url= 'http://lifeandcode.tumblr.com/post/35377038799/talking-to-strangers-a-linked-ballot-how-news'

get_disqus(url)
```

That gives you just the javascript lines that actually include the word "disqus_identifier" -- for me that reveals the fact that the value is optional. Happy to expand that if you can be more specific.